# how to handle @Cacheable if my memcached instance is down

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I have only single instance of memcached.

whenever I shut it down my java code shows exception.

What I want that it should skip caching process in this scenario.

Any work around will be helpful.

Comment: Are you using Spring ?

Comment: @mihai.ciorobea yes earlier I was using Cacheable but now I started generating keys and handling cache at code level.

Comment: I`ve changed from spymemcached-provider to xmemcached-provider. The last one is not just logging the errors, is not thawing them. Hope it hepls